# Access to the values of set()

Tags: python

Any way to access the values of BIF "set()" without using an iterator.

For instance, I got this output from my code:

```
>>> set([1,2,3])
```

How can I access it as a list?
Like:

```
>>> [1,2,3]
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use a simple type conversion:

```
>>> a
set([1, 2, 3])
>>> list(a)
[1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 4):

Make a list, like

```
list(set([1, 2, 3]))
```